# How do I get Xcode to treat an Info.plist as an iPhone/iPad Info.plist?

Tags: iphone, xcode, info.plist

I have two cocoa-touch apps in one Xcode project.  Xcode gives me iPhone/iPad related options for keys in the first's Info.plist, such as "Launch Image (iPad)".  But, Xcode gives me Mac OS X options for keys for the second, such as "Java classpaths" and "Quick Look preview height."

Here's how the project was built:

I created the new project as a Universal Window-based Application using Xcode, which came with a default Info.plist that translates raw plist keys like `UIPrerenderedIcon` to more human readable values like "Icon already includes gloss effects."  All good.

In the same Xcode Project, I added a second target, also a Cocoa-Touch application, and built it from scratch, including the Info.plist file.

I've opened up the "Active Target" project settings for both apps and have exactly one "Setting Defined at This Level": **Product Name**.  At the higher "Project Settings" level, no **Product Name** is defined and the **Info.plist File** is defined as `${EXECUTABLE_NAME}/${EXECUTABLE_NAME}-Info.plist`.  (Other settings, like **Prefix Header**, are similarly defined with variable substitution.)

Both apps build, run and use their respective Info.plist files appropriately, but Xcode still tries to give me Mac OS X Info.plist values when editing the second app's Info.plist.

How can I tell Xcode that the plist should be an iPad/iPhone Info.plist, not a Mac OS X Info.plist?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this: select/open the Info.plist in question, and then from the menu, do

View > Property List Type > iPhone Info.plist

Comment: That's it?!  It worked, you win the cupie doll, but this raises some (largely rhetorical) followup questions.  How did I miss that after using Xcode for so long?  Why isn't it in the file's Info window under "File Type"?  How can this question be up for nine days (including two with a bounty) with no one else is able to give that simple answer?

Comment: all good questions, but I don't have answers for any of them. I was surprised the question had a bounty, I wondered if I was somehow misunderstanding the question.

Comment: ps. What's a cupie doll in stackoverflow context?

Comment: The "cupie doll" would be the bounty.

Comment: I have Xcode 5.1.1 and when I make these changes to my plist it works the keys have the localized names. But the changes aren't persistent: when i switch to another file and back to the plist, the keys are shown instead of the localized key names. Any advice?

Answer (score 1):

for Xcode 5 there's no `View` -> `Property List Type` so the solution is to open the file, right click anywhere in it and right under `Show Raw Keys/Values` you'll find the `Property List Type` menu.

Happy coding,
Z.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also curious about this. I ran into the same thing while upgrading an iPhone project for iPad, and after days of trying to figure it out, I just made a new project and reimported the custom classes. I upgraded the target and this time the keys were still for iOS.

My best guess is this is an XCode bug.

Comment: If you also need the answer to this question, please upvote the question.  If Dave's answer works for you, please give him an upvote, too.